# Status bar color changed when change UINavigationBar appearance backgroundimage

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, appearance, tintcolor

I use this line of code to change navigation bar background:

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

in iOS6, it works, but in iOS5, background of the status bar is changed too, as shown in this image:
[image]

how does this happen. Thanks in advance.

One more thing, I just want to change the color of `UINavigationBar`, so I used this code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]]];
```

It works in iOS6 quite well, but does not in iOS5. What is the reason?

Comment: Did you check your `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarStyle]` is set to `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent`?

Comment: thanks, Eonil,your advice works. but is there anyway to remain the status bar style as it be, because this seems change the status bar style even after this app quits ?

Comment: Refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393348/translucent-status-bars-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch

Comment: thanks, it seems developers can change status bar at will. hope this won't offend our users. is it in the user experience guide? I have not finish reading that yet.

Comment: It's case by case. Usually changing color or hiding it (for case of immersive app) is fine, but modifying content of the status bar is usually not acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this one to set your status bar

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
```

So status bar colour will be black and font colour will be white..